# Can the search space of a solvable linear optimization problem be discontinuous?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

**Background**

Say you have a traditional linear-optimization problem, there is a linear cost function,

$\vec{c}\cdot\vec{x}$

and a set of linear constraints,

$A_1\vec{x} \geq b_1 $

$A_2\vec{x} \leq b_2 $

$A_3 \vec{x} = b_3$.

Inherently, the search space of the optimization problem is defined by a boolean AND of all the constraints.

**Question**

*If the search space is discontinuous and the definition contains a boolean OR, is it still possible to reduce the problem to the standard form?* If so, what is the method called? How does it work? Any references would be helpful.

I understand that the trivial solution would be to search each continuous subspace of the search space separately and do an iterative search through the discrete set of minima of all the subspaces. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

**Example**

The following is an example of a constraint I am working with.

$(x = 0) \vee (x > x_{min})$   where $x_{min} > 0$

Note, that there may be several variables with a similar constraint, that the variable must be zero **or** larger than a minimum value.

Comment: If $x$ takes discrete or integer or even binary values, then the search space is discontinuous. Is this your question ?

Comment: x takes the value zero or any value greater than a minimum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a linear programming problem, no.  The feasible space of a linear program is an intersection of half spaces, and as such, convex. So if there is a feasible solution with $x = 0$ and a feasible solution with $x = y$ then there is a feasible solution with $x = \alpha y$ for every $0\le alpha\le 1$.

As a mixed integer program (a linear program where some variables are constrained to be integers) then, yes, you can constrain variables to discontinuous ranges.  See the [aimms guide](http://www.aimms.com/aimms/download/manuals/aimms3om_integerprogrammingtricks.pdf) for details.  Note that while linear programming is easy (in P) integer programming is not (unless P=NP).

Comment: The link you provided was extremely relevant and helpful. Thank you!

Could you by any chance tell me the practical complexity of solving an MILP? I have a problem that only has about 21 variables and 10 constraints in addition to the cost function. If this were to be solved by something like the GLPK, any idea how many operations that would take? In the order of thousands, tens of thousand, or millions?

Comment: It strongly depends on the problem.  It will almost certainly take millions, but that takes a fraction of a second on a modern machine.  I suspect that a problem that small will probably be solved to optimality in less than a minute by a modern solver, but there are problems that small that are nearly intractable. Try it.